# Custom keyboard layout not fits on screen

Tags: android, android-custom-keyboard

I got a custom keyboard made for playing a text based game. Problem is keys not fits when I put a `verticalGap` and `horizontalGap` to have a small key gap. The cause of the keys that not fits screen is because, I have a key(main key) with height of 3 rows. So I made 2nd and 3rd row keys `40%p` for my main key (which has 40%p width). My keyboard xml for keys is: res/xml/drpgkeys.xml

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:horizontalGap="5dp"
android:keyHeight="9%p"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:verticalGap="5dp">

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="888"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyHeight="27%p"
        android:keyLabel="ADV"
        android:keyWidth="40%p" />

    <Key
        android:codes="907"
        android:keyLabel="MINE"
        android:keyWidth="30%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="905"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="CHOP"
        android:keyWidth="30%p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="906"
        android:horizontalGap="40%p"
        android:keyLabel="FORAGE"
        android:keyWidth="30%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="908"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="FISH"
        android:keyWidth="30%p" />
</Row>

<Row android:keyHeight="8%p">
    <Key
        android:codes="201"
        android:horizontalGap="40%p"
        android:keyLabel="O.o"
        android:keyWidth="12%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/inv" />
    <Key
        android:codes="334"
        android:keyLabel="Undefined"
        android:keyWidth="36%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/market" />
    <Key
        android:codes="202"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="o.O"
        android:keyWidth="12%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/ginv" />


</Row>
<Row
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key
        android:codes="900"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="STATS"
        android:keyWidth="20%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/stats" />
    <Key
        android:codes="901"
        android:keyLabel="PET"
        android:keyWidth="20%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="903"
        android:keyLabel="HEAL"
        android:keyWidth="20%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="904"
        android:keyLabel="PHEAL"
        android:keyWidth="20%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="333"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_icon"
        android:keyWidth="20%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/optionkey" />
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

and my keyboard layout is: res/layout/keyboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drpg.ddkeys.ddKeysView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@null"
android:keyTextColor="#99b3c4"
android:popupLayout="@layout/popupkeys" />
```

my `key_backgroud drawable` normal state keyboard is https://pastebin.com/raw/hTLJ8PZu 
Keyboard photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnwIN.jpg 
where, `ADV` key's height is smaller to 3rd row keys and 2nd and 3rd rows are outside screen.

Comment: couldn't add drawable file with this too, shows some error when formatting to code

Comment: I did resolved my issue by decresing **2nd** and **3rd** row keys sizes and increasing **ADV** keys height. But that doesn't compatible with every devices.

Comment: Searched all over and found something called `GridLayout`. I don't know how to implement that here.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by removing `android:horizontalGap` from **Keyboard** level and applied to **Key** level. And made horizontalGap in **%p** and adjusted every key size so my total keywidth should get **100%p**.

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyHeight="9%p"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:verticalGap="0.55%p">

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="888"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyHeight="27%p"
        android:keyLabel="ADV"
        android:keyWidth="40%p" />

    <Key
        android:codes="907"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyLabel="MINE"
        android:keyWidth="29%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="905"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="CHOP"
        android:keyWidth="29%p" />
</Row>

<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="906"
        android:horizontalGap="41%p"
        android:keyLabel="FORAGE"
        android:keyWidth="29%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="908"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="FISH"
        android:keyWidth="29%p" />
</Row>

<Row
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:keyboardMode="@integer/default_keys">
    <Key
        android:codes="201"
        android:horizontalGap="41%p"
        android:keyLabel="O.o"
        android:keyWidth="11%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/inv" />
    <Key
        android:codes="334"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyLabel="Undefined"
        android:keyWidth="35%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/market" />
    <Key
        android:codes="202"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="o.O"
        android:keyWidth="11%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/ginv" />
</Row>

<Row
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:keyboardMode="@integer/custom_keys">
    <Key
        android:codes="201"
        android:horizontalGap="41%p"
        android:keyLabel="O_o"
        android:keyWidth="11%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/customkeys_left" />
    <Key
        android:codes="334"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyLabel="Undefined"
        android:keyWidth="35%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/market" />
    <Key
        android:codes="202"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyLabel="o_O"
        android:keyWidth="11%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/customkeys_right" />
</Row>

<Row
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
    android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
    <Key
        android:codes="900"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:keyLabel="STATS"
        android:keyWidth="19.2%p"
      android:popupKeyboard="@xml/stats" />
    <Key
        android:codes="901"
        android:keyLabel="PET"
        android:keyWidth="19.2%p" 
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
    <Key
        android:codes="903"
        android:keyLabel="HEAL"
        android:keyWidth="19.2%p"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="904"
        android:keyLabel="PHEAL"
        android:keyWidth="19.2%p"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="333"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/key_icon"
        android:keyWidth="19.2%p"
        android:popupKeyboard="@xml/optionkey" 
        android:horizontalGap="1%p"/>
 </Row>
 </Keyboard>
```